# Allow multiple signatures for lambda/callback function as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, c++14, variadic-templates

I want to allow multiple signatures for a callable whose type is specified as a template parameter. More specifically, I have a templated `update` method, which takes a callable that must return a `float`, and uses it to update values in a grid of data. A simplified illustration of this is

```
template <typename Fn>
void update(Fn&& fn_)
{
    for (Vec3 pos : m_grid)
    {
        float val = fn_(pos, m_grid)
        m_grid(pos) = val;
        ...
```

In the above case, the signature of the `fn_` must always have both a pos and a grid as parameters, even if they are ignored in the implementation

I would like to use some template magic to allow multiple permutations of callback signatures.

In particular, I would like to allow callbacks that take `pos` but not `grid`, and callbacks that take no parameters at all.  I don't mind whether the ordering of parameters is enforced or not.

Anyone any hints on how to do this? I don't mind using boost or other libraries, but they should be header-only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this with a helper function using SFINAE using `is_invocable` ([C++17](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_invocable): `std::is_invocable`, or earlier with [boost](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/callable_traits/doc/html/callable_traits/reference.html#callable_traits.reference.ref_is_invocable): `boost::callable_traits::is_invocable`)

```
template <typename Fn,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable<Fn, Vec3, Grid>::value>* = nullptr>
float call_helper(Fn&& fn_, const Vec3& pos_, const Grid& grid_)
{
  return fn_(pos_, grid_);
}

template <typename Fn,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable<Fn, Vec3>::value>* = nullptr>
float call_helper(Fn&& fn_, const Vec3& pos_, const Grid& grid_)
{
  return fn_(pos_);
}

template <typename Fn,
          std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable<Fn, Grid>::value>* = nullptr>
float call_helper(Fn&& fn_, const Vec3& pos_, const Grid& grid_)
{
  return fn_(grid_);
}

template <typename Fn>
void update(Fn&& fn_)
{
    for (Vec3 pos : m_grid)
    {
        float val = call_helper(fn_, pos, m_grid)
        m_grid(pos) = val;
        ...
```

Comment: It's possible for a single functor to support more than one of these calls, in which case you'll get an ambiguous overload error.  Maybe that's what you want in that case. If not, there are also ways to prioritize the overloads (like presumably if it can be called with both args, that one should "win").

Comment: It's a tough call, but I think I prefer (at least, can understand) this solution best.  My one concern is whether the additional function call will be compiled away, i.e. will it incur any extra overhead?

Comment: It also seems that `callable_traits` is not yet released as part of boost, it has "an expected release in Boost 1.66 (December 2017)" (https://github.com/badair/callable_traits).  Unfortunate, but not a deal breaker.

Comment: I managed to do this with `std` c++14 traits, similar to `enable_if_t<is_same<result_of_t<Fn(Vec3&, Grid&), float>>::value, float>`. It's not as neat as above, but works well.  I'm fairly confident the additional function call will be optimised away, though I'd like some confirmation of that.  Regardless, I'll accept this as the answer.

Answer (score 2):

> In particular, I would like to allow callbacks that take pos but not grid, and callbacks that take no parameters at all.

Just define two overloads and use lambdas to do that by forwarding the request to the *complete* function and thus filtering the extra parameters.
As a minimal, working example:

```
struct S {
    template <typename Fn>
    auto update(Fn &&fn_)
    -> decltype(fn_(0, 0), void())
    {
        // ...
        fn_(0, 0);
        // ...
    }

    template <typename Fn>
    auto update(Fn &&fn_)
    -> decltype(fn_(0), void())
    { update([&fn_](auto a, auto) { fn_(a); }); }

    template <typename Fn>
    auto update(Fn &&fn_)
    -> decltype(fn_(), void())
    { update([&fn_](auto, auto) { fn_(); }); }
};

int main() {
    S s;
    s.update([](auto, auto) {});
    s.update([](auto) {});
    s.update([]() {});
}
```

Comment: By using `0` as the test parameters you are assuming that the type is convertible to a zero, e.g. a pointer?  Since the parameters are not pointers, then I take it that this solution requires using dummy `Vec3` and `Grid` parameters in place of the `0`s?

Comment: I used `int`s as parameters because this is a minimal example, but you can freely use whatever you want as long as the declarations differ in numbers of parameters.